# Mapping object json data into 2 separate arrays with AlamofireObjectMapper

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, xcode

I'm currently trying to implement mapping to my models and the current way I'm doing it isn't yielding any result. I have a MediaLibrary class that holds 2 arrays, 'exerciseMedia' and 'stretchMedia' that both hold an array of 'Media' objects. I've opted for the **ObjectMapper/AlamofireObjectMapper** library to map data to my models.

```
import ObjectMapper

class MediaLibrary: Mappable {

    var exerciseMedia: [Media]?
    var stretchMedia: [Media]?

    required init?(map: Map) {
        mapping(map: map)
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        exerciseMedia <- map["ExerciseMedia"]
        stretchMedia  <- map["StretchMedia"]
    }
}
```

Here is the Media object that will make up the objects populating both of my arrays in MediaLibrary class.

```
import ObjectMapper

struct Media: Mappable {

    var _id: String?
    var name: String?
    var desc: String?
    var imageURI: String?
    var videoURI: String?
    var trainerID: String?
    var isShoulders : Bool?
    var isNeck : Bool?
    var isLegs : Bool?
    var isHands : Bool?
    var isChest : Bool?
    var isCalves : Bool?
    var isButt : Bool?
    var isBack : Bool?
    var isArms : Bool?
    var isCore : Bool?
    var isFullBody : Bool?
    var isLowerBody : Bool?
    var isUpperBody : Bool?
    var isExercise : Bool?
    var isStretch : Bool?
    var equipmentNeeded : String?

    init?(map: Map){ }

    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {

        _id             <- map["_id"]
        name            <- map["name"]
        desc            <- map["desc"]
        imageURI        <- map["imageURI"]
        videoURI        <- map["videoURI"]
        trainerID       <- map["trainerID"]
        isShoulders     <- map["isShoulders"]
        isNeck          <- map["isNeck"]
        isLegs          <- map["isLegs"]
        isHands         <- map["isHands"]
        isChest         <- map["isChest"]
        isCalves        <- map["isCalves"]
        isButt          <- map["isButt"]
        isBack          <- map["isBack"]
        isArms          <- map["isArms"]
        isCore          <- map["isCore"]
        isFullBody      <- map["isFullBody"]
        isLowerBody     <- map["isLowerBody"]
        isUpperBody     <- map["isUpperBody"]
        isExercise      <- map["isExercise"]
        isStretch       <- map["isStretch"]
        equipmentNeeded <- map["equipmentNeeded"]
    }
}
```

Now here is a sample of the json I'm trying to map. Note my model has both 'imageURI' and 'videoURI' as there are 2 types of Media objects but since they're optionals it can account for this.

```
{
    "StretchMedia": [
        {
            "_id": "5a380db7ee292409b4f44980",
            "name": "somephoto",
            "desc": "some description",
            "imageURI": "https://videofitapptestbucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/100006166323",
            "trainerID": "5a32f62a28ce4acbc5fbbb4b",
            "__v": 0,
            "createdAt": "2017-12-18T18:49:27.009Z",
            "isShoulders": false,
            "isNeck": false,
            "isLegs": false,
            "isHands": false,
            "isChest": false,
            "isCalves": false,
            "isButt": false,
            "isBack": false,
            "isArms": false,
            "isCore": false,
            "isFullBody": false,
            "isLowerBody": false,
            "isUpperBody": false,
            "isExercise": false,
            "isStretch": true,
            "equipmentNeeded": "none"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5a380dfa089b2d09dcfa92db",
            "name": "somephoto",
            "desc": "some description",
            "videoURI": "https://videofitapptestbucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/100002098677",
            "trainerID": "5a32f62a28ce4acbc5fbbb4b",
            "__v": 0,
            "createdAt": "2017-12-18T18:50:34.277Z",
            "isShoulders": false,
            "isNeck": false,
            "isLegs": false,
            "isHands": false,
            "isChest": false,
            "isCalves": false,
            "isButt": false,
            "isBack": false,
            "isArms": false,
            "isCore": false,
            "isFullBody": false,
            "isLowerBody": false,
            "isUpperBody": false,
            "isExercise": false,
            "isStretch": true,
            "equipmentNeeded": "none"
        }
    ],
    "ExerciseMedia": [
        {
            "_id": "5a345a356ec5fc0032651611",
            "name": "Juan",
            "desc": "pic of some Spanish guy",
            "imageURI": "https://videofitapptestbucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/10000998839",
            "trainerID": "5a32f62a28ce4acbc5fbbb4b",
            "isStretchCore": false,
            "isExerciseCore": false,
            "__v": 0,
            "createdAt": "2017-12-15T23:26:45.461Z",
            "isShoulders": false,
            "isNeck": false,
            "isLegs": false,
            "isHands": false,
            "isChest": false,
            "isCalves": false,
            "isButt": false,
            "isBack": false,
            "isArms": false,
            "isCore": false,
            "isFullBody": true,
            "isLowerBody": false,
            "isUpperBody": false,
            "isExercise": true,
            "isStretch": false,
            "equipmentNeeded": "Dumbbells"
        }
    ],
}
```

The problem I'm having is how to populate the 2 arrays on my MediaLibrary class with the contents of "ExerciseMedia" and "StretchMedia" to their respective arrays. I've created a function that makes a request (the body only needs the trainer id) to the route that contains the JSON you just saw. I'll post my code so far.

```
import AlamofireObjectMapper

var mediaLibrary: MediaLibrary?

func setTrainerMediaLibrary(trainerID: String) {
        let body: [String: Any] = [
            "trainerID": trainerID
        ]

        Alamofire.request(TRAINER_MEDIA_ALL, method: .post, parameters: body, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: HEADER).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<MediaLibrary>) in
            if response.result.error == nil {
                self.mediaLibrary = Mapper<MediaLibrary>().map(JSONObject: response.result.value)
            } else {
                print("Could not map JSON data to Media Library model")
                debugPrint(response.result.error as Any)
            }
        }
    }
```

The MediaLibrary object returns nil so something isn't right. My thoughts are that since the MediaLibrary has mapping for both "ExerciseMedia" and "StretchMedia" that all I need to do is use the MediaLibrary in the request and the mapping function will automatically handle the 2 media keys you see in the JSON. I could be going about this completely wrong but I know I'm close, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the usage of [AlamofireObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper#usage), the object response already mapped to the json. All you need just called as `.value` and ready to use.

```
self.mediaLibrary = response.result.value
```

The usage with `Mapper<MediaLibrary>().map()` is referring to ObjectMapper library itself.

Comment: Thank you! This was so simple but very helpful